# Conditional minimum axes value for excel chart

Tags: vba, excel, axes

I am looking for some VBA code which can automate the fixed minimum value of the x axis in a chart, depending on the earliest detected date and assigning one of a number of predefined values.

I am dealing with large quantities of data wherein the start date of the available data often varies.

Is it possible to detect the earliest year value in the x-axis and apply a predetermined start date?

For example, if data is available from the 4th May 2002, the code will read the minimum value in the x-axis range as 04/05/2002, detect the '2002' and set the minimum x-axis value to '37258' to correspond with the 1st January 2002 in Excel's date numbering system.

If data is available from mid-2008, again it would set the minimum value in the x-axis to '39449' to fit with 01/01/2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = dateserial(year(ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale),1,1)
```

This looks at the chart, takes the year from that, and then sets the start to that 1/1 of that year.

Comment: I can see what you have tried to do here - and I feel like this should work. However it is not, as the minimum value stays the same as before the macro was run - equally it is not producing any error messages either.

Are you totally sure that this works for you?

Comment: Update - your code was correct, except I had to change the 'xlValue' occurrences to 'xlCategory'.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I produced a chart that simple had dates, and recorded a macro of me making the changes to the chart. That way, i got the required property. This code successfully changed the scale. use xlValue for the axis along the side, use xlCategory for the axis along the bottom, and use xlSeriesAxis for the 3d axis